# cdev initialization is linux device drivers: what is the difference between the two approaces?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, structure, linux-device-driver

In the book [Linux Device Drivers (third edition)](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/), they say:

> There are two ways of allocating and initializing one of these
>   structures. If you wish to obtain a standalone cdev structure at
>   runtime, you may do so with code such as:
>
> struct cdev *my_cdev = cdev_alloc(  );
>
> my_cdev->ops = &my_fops;
>
> Chances are, however, that you will want to embed the cdev structure
>   within a device-specific structure of your own; that is what scull
>   does. In that case, you should initialize the structure that you have
>   already allocated with:
>
> void cdev_init(struct cdev *cdev, struct file_operations *fops);

I don't understand the second part. Even if we have the cdev structure within a device-specific structure, why can't we  use the first approach for initialization?

For e.g., if I have my own device specific struct foo_dev, and my_cdev a part of it,

```
struct foo_dev my_foo_dev{
cdev* my_cdev;
...
}
```

Why couldn't I just use

`my_foo_dev->my_cdev = cdev_alloc(  ); 
 my_foo_dev->my_cdev->ops = &my_fops;` ?

Specifically, instead of using the cdev_init() fucntion, can we not just initialize the individual members of cdev structure using assignment? Or does cdev_init() perform any extra tasks?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo yes I checked that out. However it didn't clear my doubt. The top voted answer for example, says "However cdev_init is the new mechanism in this we have to pass cdev structure variable (or already initialized cdev structure pointer) and file operation variable". From it I didn't understand the need for a new function? We could just have initialized the fops using assignment as done earlier.

Comment: You can't initialize a `struct cdev` (_not_ `struct cdev*`) with `cdev_alloc`. Also, it's still a duplicate, regardless of the quality of the answers.

Comment: Do not extend your question. If there are new aspects, ask a new question. Notet that what you are asking is not only related to the Linux kernel, not even C-specific, but basic programming knowledge.

Comment: @Olaf There was a header saying your question might be a duplicate, if not explain in detail why. that's why I added the last two lines.

Comment: Header?? And: I did not even ask a question!

Comment: oops. by your I mean mine :o SO was asking me to clarify the question further if it's not a duplicate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cdev_alloc` allocates a new `struct cdev` object and returns a pointer to it.

`cdev_init` intializes an existing uninitialized `struct cdev`, allocated by you.

Effectively, `cdev_alloc` would be equivalent to:

```
struct cdev* p = malloc(sizeof(struct cdev));
cdev_init(p, opts);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. however, I still have doubts. Is the difference in the two approaches, according to you, only a matter of static and dynamic memory allocation? If so, I still don't see why we need a seperate initializaion function in the second case and not in the first. But then in your addendum, you say that cdev_alloc also inializaes the pointer? can you point to some reference? according to the ldd book, the explicitly initialize the ops after the call to cdev_alloc.

Comment: @Lavya: It is about allocating just a `struct cdev` or a (larger) struct **which includes** a `struct cdev`.

Comment: @Olaf thanks. So we can avoid cdev_init if we just initialize all it's needed member (fop etc) individually?

Comment: @Lavya: **DO NOT**! THis is like a C++ constructor; what if the definition of that struct changes? What if the meaning of fields changes? What would be the reason to anyway?

Comment: @Olaf Now that make a lot of sense. Thanks for clearing!

Comment: @Olaf @ Colonel I went through the code (should have done it before asking..). http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/char_dev.c#L538. Apart from fops, the function is also doing the following initializations: 541         INIT_LIST_HEAD(&cdev->list);
542         kobject_init(&cdev->kobj, &ktype_cdev_default);  cdev_alloc does these as well hence the only things we need to initialize explicitly are fops and module*. It's clearer to me now. Thank you both of you for your help and patience!